# Getting Modified Html string in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to remove all the checkboxes from the found html but when I check the string checkboxes are all there?:

```
$('#viewPdf').click(function () {

        var html = $('#mCSB_2 > .mCSB_container').html();

        $('input:checkbox', html).each(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        alert(html);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Misunderstood/read the OP.

Here's a way to do this

```
// Create a new DOM object:

htmlDom = $(html);

// remove the inputs

htmlDom.remove(':checkbox')

// get the html

html = htmlDoc.html()
```

Comment: He says he wants to remove them from the string, not the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#viewPdf').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mCSB_2 .mCSB_container input:checkbox').each(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    alert($('#mCSB_2 .mCSB_container').html());

});
```

Comment: I don't want to operate on the DOM but the string or a copy of it so that the original html should not be modified.